# Y is {-1, 0, 1} and expected value of Y is 0 and the varriance is 1/2 . What is the probability distribution of Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**A random variable Y can only take values in {-1, 0, 1}. The expected value of Y is 0 and it's variance is 1/2. Find the probability distribution of Y.**

I understand the question wants me to find the probabilities of Y being -1,0, 1

How do I use the given information (expected value and variance) to calculate the probability distribution of Y? As in what method should I use?

Comment: Do you know how to compute expected value and variance? Try giving names to the probabilities, say $p_{-1}=P(Y=-1)$, $p_0=P(Y=0)$, and $p_1=P(Y=1)$, and plug these into the formulas for expected value and variance. Also plug in $0$ for the expected value and $\frac{1}{2}$ for the variance, and see if you can solve for $p_{-1}$, $p_0$, and $p_1$.

Comment: Hint: start by writing an _explicit expression_ (meaning no fancy stuff like $\displaystyle\sum_{i=-1}^1\ldots$) for the expected value of $Y$. Repeat for the variance of $Y$. _Edit_ your question to include this stuff into it.

Comment: I know how to callculate the expected value add -1, 0, 1 then divide it by 3. And for the variance subtract the mean from all the values of Y while adding them then multiply them by 1/2 in this case

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am not sure what you mean by explicit expression

Comment: You have three unknowns, right?  You also have three equations that those unknowns satisfy.  One you might be overlooking is the fact the three probabilities sum up to $1$.  The other two are the expected value and variance of the probability distribution.  The "explicit expression" of the expected value and variance (in terms of the three discrete probabilities)  should be well-known to you.

Comment: "I know how to calculate the expected value $\ldots$" Alas, you neither know how to calculate the expected value, nor how to calculate the variance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you *aren't* yet as familiar with finding expectations and
variances as you need to be. Hardly a crime. So here is an outline. I think you can
fill in any gaps.

To start,
define $p_{-1}, p_0,$ and $p_1$ as suggested in the helpful hint by @kccu.

Then $E(Y) = (-1)p_{-1} + (0)p_0 + (1)p_1 = -p_{-1} + p_1 = 0.$
So $p_{-1} = p_1.$

Also, $V(Y) = E[(Y - \mu)^2] = 1/2,$ where $\mu = E(Y) = 0.$
From which we get $$V(Y) = (-1-0)^2p_{-1} + (0-0)^2p_0 + (1-0)^2p_1 = p_{-1} + p_1 = 2p_1 = 1/2.$$

So $p_1 = 1/4 = p_{-1},$ leaving $p_0 = 1/2.$

Comment: Shouldn't your variance value of 2p1 be divided with n? Which would be 3 in this case since Y has a possible of three values -1, 0, 1.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing sample variance with variance of a random variable. Look for formula similar to $V(Y) = \sum_y (y - \mu)^2 f_Y(y).$

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you.